# Disable button onclick but enable another button

Tags: javascript, html

I have two different buttons on my page. I want them both to be enabled when the page loads, but when a user clicks one I would like to disable the other button. But if they click the other button, I would like that button to disabled as well while enabling the other disabled button. I have been able to disable the button onclick, but I'm having trouble getting the other button to re-enable . Here are the two buttons that I have on the page. They are not in a form, just on the page.

```
<button onclick="down7913.disabled=false" type="submit" class="positive" name="up7913"><img src="check.png" alt=""/></button>

<button onclick="this.disabled=true" type="submit" class="negative" name="down7913"><img src="cross.png" alt=""/></button>
```

Comment: If you have no problems with jQuery, I can provide you the solution.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/2jBtV/

Comment: Thanks Musa...Could you add yours as an answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Check this code, it's in your flavour and working:

Code Snippet -

```html
<button
    onclick="this.disabled=true;document.getElementById('down7913').disabled=false;"
    type="submit"
    class="positive"
    name="up7913"
    id="up7913"
  >
    First
  </button>

  <button
    onclick="this.disabled=true;document.getElementById('up7913').disabled=false;"
    type="submit"
    class="negative"
    name="down7913"
    id="down7913"
  >
    Second
  </button>
```

Comment: How can I use it without the disabled attribute?

Comment: @Sohan Can u please elaborate about `without the disabled attribute` ?

Comment: I just wanted to disable and enable without using the "disabled" property. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 3):

You should write functions:

```
function disablefirstbutton() {
    document.getElementById("firstbutton").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("secondbutton").disabled = false;
}

function disablesecondbutton() {
    document.getElementById("secondbutton").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("firstbutton").disabled = false;
}

<button id="firstbutton" onclick="disablefirstbutton()">
<button id="secondbutton" onclick="disablesecondbutton()">
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using jQuery, here it is!

```
$(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        var classname = $(this).attr('class');

        if(classname == 'positive')
        { 
            $('button.positive').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('button.negative').attr('disabled', false);
        }
        else
        {
            $('button.negative').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('button.positive').attr('disabled', false);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('negative')[0].disabled=false"
```

That is pure javascript and please note the `document.getElementsByClassName('negative')` returns an `array` of all classes.  If there is only one, then it will work as I wrote.  If not, then I would add an id and use `document.getElementById('buttonId').disabled=false`.