# CSS button not maintaining focus formatting

Tags: html, css, focus

I'm attempting to make two buttons where, when one is focused, the other is unfocused. So far I have the following code.

```css
  .btn {
    border: none;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-size: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: blue;
  }

  .btn:focus {
    border: none;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: dimgrey;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="this.disabled=true;document.getElementById('down7913').disabled=false;" type="submit" class="btn positive" name="up7913" id="up7913" >Full</button>|
<button onclick="this.disabled=true;document.getElementById('up7913').disabled=false;" type="submit" class="btn negative" name="down7913" id="down7913" >Short</button>
```

However, the focused formatting is only applied while the button is being actively pressed. After the button is released, the unfocused formatting is applied immediately. I know that the html does what I want it to do (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112537/disable-button-onclick-but-enable-another-button/11112666)). So how do I get the focused formatting to persist? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m7nz3f0a/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS try,

```
  .btn:focus, btn:active {
    border: none;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: dimgrey;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
```

Or, try this:

```
  .btn:disabled {
    border: none;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: dimgrey;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
```

`.btn:disabled` is guaranteed to work.

Comment: Good thinking. However, this does not work. I just tried it in the jsfiddle.

Comment: @NikhilMishra not possible bro, you might have done something wrong there. It literally works on my browser, Chrome's latest version.

Comment: Try running it in the jsfiddle I linked. This definitely should work, but it's not. That's why I'm confused.

Comment: @NikhilMishra Alright, I'll try to make it work then share the code with you.

Comment: @NikhilMishra Is there any room for JS?

Comment: @NikhilMishra Changed the code, now try this, I am 100% sure it would work, even tested it.